# Java InputStream blocking only if used InputStreamReader

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to access the underlying InputStream of the InputStreamReader but it only blocks even though there is data, when I use InputStream with out InputStreamReader it reads, when I add InputStreamReader to InputStream, I can no longer use the underlying InputStream or it will block.

```
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
OutputStream theOutput = socket.getOutputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));

String line = br.readLine();
System.out.println(line);
if(line.equals(Operation_Map_Upload)){
  String MapName = br.readLine();
  System.out.println(MapName);

  String MapMaker = br.readLine();
  System.out.println(MapMaker);
  String MapData = br.readLine();
  System.out.println(MapData);

  int ThumbnailSize = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
  System.out.println(ThumbnailSize);
  byte[] Thumbnail = new byte[ThumbnailSize];
  in.read(Thumbnail, 0, ThumbnailSize); // <---block here
  int MapID = SaveMap(MapName, MapMaker, MapData, Thumbnail);

  theOutput.write(("Success;" + MapID).getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
  theOutput.flush();    
}
```

If I read one more line using InputStreamReader it reads ok, but if instead I try to read 1 byte using InputStream it will block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct. `InputStreamReader` is buffered so it reads ahead, so the next byte you read directly from the `InputStream` won't be the one you want anyway. You can't do this.

Comment: So what do you suggest I do instead of using an InputStreamReader ?